# Classify the group of order $120$ using Sylow Theorem.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Classify the group of order $120$ using Sylow Theorem.

**Answer:**

$120=2^{3} \times 3 \times 5$

The number of Sylow-$2$ subgroup is $n_2=2k+1, \ k=0,1,2,........$ such that $n_2|120$.

For $k=0$, $n_2=1|120$,

For $k=1$, $n_2=3|120$,

For $k=2$, $n_2=5|120$,

For $k=3$, $n_2=7 $ does not divide $120$.

Now we have to eliminate the extra possibility.

But I can not eliminate the extra options.

Please help me

Comment: You're missing $k=7$.

Comment: please do all cases